# Writing to child process file descriptor

Tags: c, file-descriptor, child-process

I have a program "Sample" which takes input both from stdin and a non-standard file descriptor (3 or 4) as shown below

```
int pfds[2];
pipe(pfds);    
printf("%s","\nEnter input for stdin");
read(0, pO, 5);    
printf("\nEnter input for fds 3");
read(pfds[0], pX, 5);

printf("\nOutput stout");
write(1, pO, strlen(pO));    
printf("\nOutput fd 4");
write(pfds[1], pX, strlen(pX));
```

Now i have another program "Operator" which executes the above program(Sample) in a child process using execv. Now what i want is to send input to "Sample" through the "Operator" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After forking the child process, but before calling `execve`, you'll have to call `dup2(2)` to redirect the child process' `stdin` descriptor to the read end of your pipe. Here is a simple piece of code without much error checking:

```
pipe(pfds_1); /* first pair of pipe descriptors */
pipe(pfds_2); /* second pair of pipe descriptors */

switch (fork()) {
  case 0: /* child */
    /* close write ends of both pipes */
    close(pfds_1[1]);
    close(pfds_2[1]);

    /* redirect stdin to read end of first pipe, 4 to read end of second pipe */
    dup2(pfds_1[0], 0);
    dup2(pfds_2[0], 4);

    /* the original read ends of the pipes are not needed anymore */
    close(pfds_1[0]);
    close(pfds_2[0]);

    execve(...);
    break;

  case -1:
    /* could not fork child */
    break;

  default: /* parent */
    /* close read ends of both pipes */
    close(pfds_1[0]);
    close(pfds_2[0]);

    /* write to first pipe (delivers to stdin in the child) */
    write(pfds_1[1], ...);
    /* write to second pipe (delivers to 4 in the child) */
    write(pfds_2[1], ...);
    break;
}
```

This way everything you write to the first pipe from the parent process will be delivered to the child process via descriptor `0` (`stdin`), and everything you write from the second pipe will be delivered to descriptor `4` as well.

Comment: And how do i redirect the other file descriptor of the child process to the read end

Comment: @scholar: you can create a second pair of pipes with the `pipe` system call and do a `dup2(pfds_2[0], 4)` as well. Writing from `pfds_2[1]` from the parent will deliver to file descriptor `4` in the child.

Comment: This way i can write to the file descriptor for stdin but how do i write to the other file descriptor of the "Sample" program .

Comment: So erm, you have now implemented popen(3).

Comment: @Mel: Almost, but you can't tell `popen` to write to anything except `stdin`.