# Pipe() fork() and exec

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork, pipe

I try to add pipe in a mini-shell. 
I'm confused, when I type ls | sort, nothing is displayed, I don't understand why :

```
int fd[2];
if (tube == 1){

    int pipeling = pipe(fd);
    if (pipeling == -1){
        perror("pipe") ;
    }
}


    tmp = fork();               //FORK A

    if (tmp < 0){
        perror("fork");
        continue;
    }

    if (tmp != 0) {                 //parent
                while(wait(0) != tmp) ;
                continue ;
    }

    if (tube == 1) {                //there is a pipe

    if (tmp != 0){                  //parent A
        close(fd[1]);
    }

        if (tmp == 0){              //Child A                     
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            close(fd[1]);
            execv(mot[0], mot);
    }

    int tmp2 = fork() ;             //FORK B

    if (tmp2 != 0) {                //Parent B
        close(fd[0]);
        while(wait(0) != tmp2) ;
        continue ;
    }

    if (tmp2 == 0){                 //Child B
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(mot[1], mot);

    }
}
```

I've read all topics about that but it doesn't work.
Can you help me ?

Edit : the second code, I try to change the structure.

thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953386/writing-to-child-process-file-descriptor/5954324#5954324

Comment: Check system calls for errors - you are at least dup2'ing a close'd fd at one point.  What is "mot" ?  My *guess* is that your execvp arguments are incorrect.

Comment: @pilcrow, I've edited the code, mot is command given on the command line.

Comment: In your link, they use two pair of file descriptors, I don't understand why, fd[2] should works no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `fork` is not going to be reached in case `execvp` succeeds, because the latter should replace the image of the process and will stop executing the current code.

You have to restructure your program.