# Launching a console app from gui front-end

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

Could you please tell me the best way to do it? I can use popen, but it is nesessary to create a large buffer for arguments every time I need to launch my application. I can use fork + execv, but then the program writes to stdout and I cant read the output ( to display it in the text field ) Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the creation of the arguments buffer isn't such a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Of course not, but my app itself uses quite a small amount of memory & cpu.

Comment: You can create a pipe and still use fork-exec: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953386/writing-to-child-process-file-descriptor

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please tell me the best way to do it? I can use popen, but it is nesessary to create a large buffer for arguments every time I need to launch my application.

`popen()` is one good standard way if you only need one way communication with the child application, like writing to its `stdin` or reading from `stdout`, but not both.

When using C one needs to be comfortable with strings. It helps a lot to use [a string library for C](http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison) to ease string operations, such as string concatenation in your case, because the standard C library provides only basic low-level functions for that.

> I can use fork + execv, but then the program writes to stdout and I cant read the output ( to display it in the text field )

`popen()` gives you a `FILE*` pointer to the child program's `stdout` from which you can read its output using the standard C I/O function [`fread()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) or [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/). Again, the standard C library [has this functionality](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/) and it pays to familiarize yourself with it.

> Is there any other solution?

You can make the child program write to a file and then read that file, but in any case you need to be able to construct the command line string and read the file.

Comment: _You can make the child program write to a file and then read that file, but in any case you need to be able to construct the command line string and read the file._ - that is a totally half-assed solution. The "other" solution is to implement the essential functionality of `popen` yourself - create a `pipe(2)`, do a `fork(2)`, then in the child do `dup2(2)` on stdout and the write end of the pipe, and finally `execve(2)`.

Comment: Not sure what prompted your response, I did not say that one can't do pipe-fork-exec. Still, you need to read from `FILE*` or a file descriptor, this is what I meant by `being able to read the file`.

Comment: Thank you Blagovest, it's exactly what I need. Maxim, my prog is too small to link with any libraries, except libc.